# GDB core dump see content of container

Tags: c++, gdb

I am poking around in a core dump ( for the first time ) and I am interested in the elements of a map m_my_map
I can see the map with info args, but it also gives the following output

```
info args
m_my_map = <error reading variable m_my_map (Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0xf3)
```

and when I try to see its content with

```
print m_my_map 
Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0xf3
```

Is there a way to loop through the map and print the pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DWARF opcode 0xf3 comes from the "user" area of the opcode range; but it is probably `DW_OP_GNU_entry_value`, which is a GNU extension in DWARF 4 (now standardized in DWARF 5, but with a different value).

What this means for you is that you are most likely using a GDB that was released before the version of GCC that you are using.  The solution to your problem, then, is to upgrade GDB.  After you do this, printing the map will most likely work.